# python distutils - LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libMySQL.lib'

Tags: python, distutils

I'm trying to compile the .pyd file using the following setup.py file on windows
{

```
setup(name='quickfix',
      version='1.14.3',
      py_modules=['quickfix', 'quickfixt11', 'quickfix40', 'quickfix41', 'quickfix42', 'quickfix43', 'quickfix44', 'quickfix50', 'quickfix50sp1', 'quickfix50sp2'],
      data_files=[('share/quickfix', glob.glob('spec/FIX*.xml'))],
      author='Oren Miller',
      author_email='oren@quickfixengine.org',
      maintainer='Oren Miller',
      maintainer_email='oren@quickfixengine.org',
      description="FIX (Financial Information eXchange) protocol implementation",
      url='http://www.quickfixengine.org',
      download_url='http://www.quickfixengine.org',
      license=license,
      include_dirs=['C++','C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/include','C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib'],
      #library_dirs=['C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib'],
      #cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext_subclass },
      ext_modules=[Extension('_quickfix', glob.glob('C++/*.cpp'), libraries=['Ws2_32', 'odbc32', 'odbccp32'], extra_compile_args=['/EHsc', '/DHAVE_STD_TR1_SHARED_PTR'])],
)
```

}

I get this error:
{

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libMySQL.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104
```

}

Any ideas on how to fix this? How do I create a reference to the libMySQL.lib?

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually read the setup.py file?

Comment: yep - adding back library_dirs=['C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib'] doesn't fix the problem

Comment: And is the file actually in that location?

Comment: libmysql.lib and libmysql.dll are both in C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib

Comment: That's not the path given in the file.

Comment: changing library_dirs to ['C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib'] ....gives the same error message if I also uncomment it and run setup.py again

Answer (score 0):

I ended up including the libmysql.lib and libmysql.dll files in the same directory as the setup.py file which seems to have solved the error, but now I have a new one (possibly related..):

```
MySQLStore.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strptime referenced in function "private: void __thiscall FIX::MySQLStore::populateCache(void)" (?populateCache@MySQLStore@FIX@@AAEXXZ)
build\lib.win32-2.7\_quickfix.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

MySQLStore.h:

```
/* -*- C++ -*- */

/****************************************************************************
** Copyright (c) 2001-2014
**
** This file is part of the QuickFIX FIX Engine
**
** This file may be distributed under the terms of the quickfixengine.org
** license as defined by quickfixengine.org and appearing in the file
** LICENSE included in the packaging of this file.
**
** This file is provided AS IS with NO WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, INCLUDING THE
** WARRANTY OF DESIGN, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
**
** See http://www.quickfixengine.org/LICENSE for licensing information.
**
** Contact ask@quickfixengine.org if any conditions of this licensing are
** not clear to you.
**
****************************************************************************/

#ifndef HAVE_MYSQL
#error MySQLStore.h included, but HAVE_MYSQL not defined
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_MYSQL
#ifndef FIX_MYSQLSTORE_H
#define FIX_MYSQLSTORE_H

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning( disable : 4503 4355 4786 4290 )
#pragma comment( lib, "libMySQL" )
#endif

#include "MessageStore.h"
#include "SessionSettings.h"
#include "MySQLConnection.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

namespace FIX
{
/// Creates a MySQL based implementation of MessageStore.
class MySQLStoreFactory : public MessageStoreFactory
{
public:
  static const std::string DEFAULT_DATABASE;
  static const std::string DEFAULT_USER;
  static const std::string DEFAULT_PASSWORD;
  static const std::string DEFAULT_HOST;
  static const short DEFAULT_PORT;

  MySQLStoreFactory( const SessionSettings& settings )
: m_settings( settings ), m_useSettings( true ), m_useDictionary( false ) 
  {
    bool poolConnections = false;
    try { poolConnections = settings.get().getBool(MYSQL_STORE_USECONNECTIONPOOL); }
    catch( ConfigError& ) {}

    m_connectionPoolPtr = MySQLConnectionPoolPtr
      ( new MySQLConnectionPool(poolConnections) );
  }

  MySQLStoreFactory( const Dictionary& dictionary )
: m_dictionary( dictionary ), m_useSettings( false ), m_useDictionary( true ) 
  {
    m_connectionPoolPtr = MySQLConnectionPoolPtr
      ( new MySQLConnectionPool(false) );
  }

  MySQLStoreFactory( const std::string& database, const std::string& user,
                     const std::string& password, const std::string& host,
                     short port )
: m_database( database ), m_user( user ), m_password( password ), m_host( host ), m_port( port ),
  m_useSettings( false ), m_useDictionary( false ) 
  {
    m_connectionPoolPtr = MySQLConnectionPoolPtr
      ( new MySQLConnectionPool(false) );
  }

  MySQLStoreFactory()
: m_database( DEFAULT_DATABASE ), m_user( DEFAULT_USER ), m_password( DEFAULT_PASSWORD ),
  m_host( DEFAULT_HOST ), m_port( DEFAULT_PORT ), m_useSettings( false ), m_useDictionary( false ) 
  {
    m_connectionPoolPtr = MySQLConnectionPoolPtr
      ( new MySQLConnectionPool(false) );
  }

  MessageStore* create( const SessionID& );
  void destroy( MessageStore* );
private:
  MessageStore* create( const SessionID& s, const Dictionary& );

  MySQLConnectionPoolPtr m_connectionPoolPtr;
  SessionSettings m_settings;
  Dictionary m_dictionary;
  std::string m_database;
  std::string m_user;
  std::string m_password;
  std::string m_host;
  short m_port;
  bool m_useSettings;
  bool m_useDictionary;
};
/*! @} */

/// MySQL based implementation of MessageStore.
class MySQLStore : public MessageStore
{
public:
  MySQLStore( const SessionID& s, const DatabaseConnectionID& d, MySQLConnectionPool* p );
  MySQLStore( const SessionID& s, const std::string& database, const std::string& user,
                   const std::string& password, const std::string& host, short port );
  ~MySQLStore();

  bool set( int, const std::string& ) throw ( IOException );
  void get( int, int, std::vector < std::string > & ) const throw ( IOException );

  int getNextSenderMsgSeqNum() const throw ( IOException );
  int getNextTargetMsgSeqNum() const throw ( IOException );
  void setNextSenderMsgSeqNum( int value ) throw ( IOException );
  void setNextTargetMsgSeqNum( int value ) throw ( IOException );
  void incrNextSenderMsgSeqNum() throw ( IOException );
  void incrNextTargetMsgSeqNum() throw ( IOException );

  UtcTimeStamp getCreationTime() const throw ( IOException );

  void reset() throw ( IOException );
  void refresh() throw ( IOException );

private:
  void populateCache();

  MemoryStore m_cache;
  MySQLConnection* m_pConnection;
  MySQLConnectionPool* m_pConnectionPool;
  SessionID m_sessionID;
};
}

#endif //FIX_MYSQLSTORE_H
#endif //HAVE_MYSQL
```

Here is what I think are the important parts of MySQLStore.cpp

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include "stdafx.h"
#else
#include "config.h"
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_MYSQL

#include "MySQLStore.h"
#include "SessionID.h"
#include "SessionSettings.h"
#include "FieldConvertors.h"
#include "Parser.h"
#include "Utility.h"
#include "strptime.h"
#include <fstream>
```

..and..

```
void MySQLStore::populateCache()
{
  std::stringstream queryString;

  queryString << "SELECT creation_time, incoming_seqnum, outgoing_seqnum FROM sessions WHERE "
  << "beginstring=" << "\"" << m_sessionID.getBeginString().getValue() << "\" and "
  << "sendercompid=" << "\"" << m_sessionID.getSenderCompID().getValue() << "\" and "
  << "targetcompid=" << "\"" << m_sessionID.getTargetCompID().getValue() << "\" and "
  << "session_qualifier=" << "\"" << m_sessionID.getSessionQualifier() << "\"";

  MySQLQuery query( queryString.str() );
  if( !m_pConnection->execute(query) )
    throw ConfigError( "No entries found for session in database" );

  int rows = query.rows();
  if( rows > 1 )
    throw ConfigError( "Multiple entries found for session in database" );

  if( rows == 1 )
  {
    struct tm time;
    std::string sqlTime = query.getValue( 0, 0 );
    strptime( sqlTime.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &time );
    m_cache.setCreationTime (UtcTimeStamp (&time));
    m_cache.setNextTargetMsgSeqNum( atol( query.getValue( 0, 1 ) ) );
    m_cache.setNextSenderMsgSeqNum( atol( query.getValue( 0, 2 ) ) );
  }
```

The file strptime.h is in the 'C++' folder, so should be being included....

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
extern "C"
  char *
  strptime( const char *buf, const char *fmt, struct tm *tm );

#endif
```

Any ideas?
Thanks very much

Comment: reposted as a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456332/quickfix-on-windows-with-mysql-compile-error-python-2-7)

Comment: This is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456332/quickfix-on-windows-with-mysql-compile-error-python-2-7):