# quickfix on windows with mysql - compile error python 2.7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, quickfix

I get this error while trying to compile quickfix on windows for python with a mysql back-end using setuptools:

```
MySQLStore.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strptime referenced in function "private: void __thiscall FIX::MySQLStore::populateCache(void)" (?populateCache@MySQLStore@FIX@@AAEXXZ)
build\lib.win32-2.7\_quickfix.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

I don't have visual studio installed (or have any experience with it), is there a way I can fix this without it?

Thanks,

Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I hadn't included the strptime.c file (renamed to strptime.cpp) and also amended this file to include the strptime.h header